Unable to run android app with flutter run due to AppsflyerSdkPlugin.java errors
After upgrading to appsflyer_sdk: ^6.15.1 I can no longer run my flutter app on android.
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Upgrade appsflyer_sdk to 6.15.1
Do flutter run in your terminal

Below is a snippet of the multitude of errors I am getting
bad class file: /Users/yonko/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9dd547163521c1703fdc82b55e52e7bc/transformed/jetified-af-android-sdk-6.15.1-api.jar(/com/appsflyer/AFAdRevenueData.class)
    class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/appsflyer_sdk-6.15.1/android/src/main/java/com/appsflyer/appsflyersdk/AppsflyerSdkPlugin.java:13: error: cannot access AFLogger
import com.appsflyer.AFLogger;

bad class file: /Users/yonko/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9dd547163521c1703fdc82b55e52e7bc/transformed/jetified-af-android-sdk-6.15.1-api.jar(/com/appsflyer/AFLogger.class)
    class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/appsflyer_sdk-6.15.1/android/src/main/java/com/appsflyer/appsflyersdk/AppsflyerSdkPlugin.java:14: error: cannot access AppsFlyerConsent
import com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerConsent;
                    ^

Output of flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.93.0)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

I have updated my java version as this issue was experienced on our fastlane pipeline and upgrading java resolved that. But it did not resolve for my machine (macOS Sonoma 14.5).
I have also opened an issue on the Appsflyer GitHub thread 

Try to delete all the directories named like 'appsflyer_sdk' in /.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/, then execute flutter pub get and run again.

use 6.15.0
My Android App also use appsflyer, 6.15.1 has problems.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
